# mainframe - generate a report with sum of particular fields

Tags: mainframe, jcl, dfsort

I have a VSAM which has

• 4-byte binary unsigned integer representing a 6-digit decimal branch sortcode (e.g. 420101)

• 4-byte binary unsigned integer representing an 8-digit account number (e.g. 12345678)

• 4-byte signed integer holding the account's current balance

• 32-byte EBCDIC character account owner name (e.g. “PAT JONES”), blank padded on the right

and I want to generate a report as below

[image]

I was trying to do this

```
  INCLUDE COND=(1,7,CH,EQ,C'some sortcode')                              
  SORT FIELDS=(1,7,CH,A)                                            
  SUM FIELDS=(9,2,BI)
```

But there's plenty of sortcode. I am thinking of sort all the inputs and then sum every record that has the same sortcode together right underneath these sortcode rows. Is there any way in JCL I can do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
//SORTSTEP EXEC PGM=SORT
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*
//SORTIN   DD DSN=YourInputDataset,DISP=SHR
//SORTOUT  DD DSN=YourOutputDataset,
//          DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE)
//SYSIN  DD *
  SORT FIELDS=(1,4,BI,A)
  INREC BUILD=(1,4,BI,TO=ZD,LENGTH=6,5,4,9,4,13,32)
  OUTFIL REMOVECC,
         SECTIONS=(1,6,
         HEADER3=(1:C'LIST OF BANK BY BRANCH',/,X,/,
                  1:C'SORTCODE:    ',1,6,/,X,/,
                  1:C'ACCOUNT',10:C'BALANCE',20:C'OWNER NAME',/,
                  1:C'-------',10:C'-------',20:C'----------'),
         TRAILER3=(X,/,
      1:C'BRANCH TOTAL: ',16:TOT=(11,4,BI,EDIT=(SIIIITTT),SIGNS=(,-)))),
         TRAILER1=(X,/,1:C'GRAND TOTAL: ',TOT=(11,4,BI,
                        EDIT=(SIIIITTT),SIGNS=(,-))),
        OUTREC=(1:7,4,BI,TO=ZD,LENGTH=8,10:11,4,BI,EDIT=(SIIIITTT),
                        SIGNS=(,-),20:15,32)
/*
```

You can find about more about SECTIONS, HEADER3 and TRAILER3 at this link: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.iceg200/ice2cg_Sections.htm

Comment: Nvm, sorted it out. Thanks a lot.